# Modal form is nil after creation

Tags: forms, delphi, null, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create an instance of a form and pass a parameter, that has to be specific to that instance.

```
type
  TDataForm = class(TForm)
    { Some components}
    { Some procedures }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; Data: PData; Page: String); reintroduce;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    ViewedData: PData;
  end;

var CharacterScreen: TDataForm;

implementation
```

CharacterScreen is a var for one of sucn instances. When i'm opening than instance, i'm doing it like this:

```
constructor TDataForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent; Data: PData; Page: String);
begin
inherited Create(nil);
ViewedData:=Data;
if Page='Stats'      then CharPageControl.TabIndex:=0;
if Page='Equipment'  then CharPageControl.TabIndex:=1;
if Page='Effects'    then CharPageControl.TabIndex:=2;
if Page='Statistics' then CharPageControl.TabIndex:=3;
ShowModal;
Free;
end;

CharacterScreen:=TDataForm.Create(nil,@Data,'Page 1');
```

Howewer, if later i'm calling some procedure for than form, i get an AV error. When watching CharacterScreen variable in step-by-step debug, it's described as nil.

So my question is: what is the correct way to create an instance of a form (so that later i can create a second instance and so on)? Also, is it a correct way to store an instance of variable ViewedData, that has to be unique to each instance of a form?

Comment: Don't call Free in the constructor. Simple.

Comment: More than removing Free from the constructor, remove the ShowModal call too. That should be made outside the constructor. Also, remove the global form variable. You don't need it. For a modal form you always use local variables for the form reference.

Comment: If you just want to show the dialog and forget about it afterwards, you can add a static method to your form (call it Execute for example) and create/showmodal/free the form in that method...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you call Free from the constructor, so the instance will become inaccessible when you close the form.

You can add a static method to the form and call that from other forms.

it is best practice to remove the global form variable so that the calling code must declare a local variable (will become apparent when you create multiple instances of the same form).
In this example, I made the constructor private, so that only the execute method can be called outside this unit.

```
type
  TDataForm = class(TForm)
    { Some components}
    { Some procedures }
  private
    { Private declarations }
    ViewedData: PData;
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    class procedure Execute(Data: PData; APage: String);
  end;

implementation

class function TDataForm.Execute(Data: PData; APage: String) :TDataForm;

begin
 Result := TDataForm.Create(nil);
 Result.ViewedData := PData;
 if APage='Характеристики' then Result.CharPageControl.TabIndex:=0 else
 if APage='Экипировка'     then Result.CharPageControl.TabIndex:=1 else
 if APage='Эффекты'        then Result.CharPageControl.TabIndex:=2 else
 if APage='Статистика'     then Result.CharPageControl.TabIndex:=3;
 Result.ShowModal;
end;

constructor TDataForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
 inherited Create(nil);
end;
```

now you call your form like this:

```
var CharacterScreen : TDataForm;

CharacterScreen := TDataForm.Execute(@Data,'Page 1');
try
 // do something with CharacterScreen when it has been closed
finally
 CharacterScreen.Free;   
end;
```

** **UPDATE** **

Now If I were you I would do something like this (pseudo code, I assume you'll get the idea) :

```
Unit character;

type
  TCharacterData = class
  public
   // some public fields
  end;

...

Unit EditCharacter;

type 
  TDataForm = class(TForm)
    procedure OnShow(Sender : TObject);
  public
    class procedure Execute(Data : TCharacterData) : Boolean;  
  end;

implementation;

class function TDataForm.Execute(var Character: TCharacter) : Boolean;

var Frm: TDataForm ;

begin
 Result := False; 
 Frm:= TDataForm.Create(nil);
 try
  Frm.Character := Character;
  Frm.ShowModal;
  Result := Frm.ModalResult = mrOK;
 finally
  Frm.Free;
 end;
end;

procedure TDataForm.OnShow(Sender : TObject);
 begin
  if Character = TWizardCharacter then Frm.CharPageControl.TabIndex:=0 else
  if Character = TBarbarianCharacter then Frm.CharPageControl.TabIndex:=1
   ... //etc
 end;
```

now the calling code can look like this

```
var Character : TCharacter;
...

Character := TWizardCharacter.Create;

...
// user wants to edit character

procedure EditCharacter;
begin
 if TDataForm.Execute(Character)  then
  begin
   // user has modified character, act accordingly
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Big improvement, although in the long run I'd probably not make this method static and/or not make it part of the form class.

Comment: @GolezTrol: can you expand on why not? I use this all the time (although I refactored this in a ancestor form class)

Comment: Mainly because it makes it harder to test and to separate concerns. I try to use inversion of control now, using Spring4D, which opens a lot of possibilities for, amongst others, unit testing. Having a static implementation of calling a modal form, implies that it becomes virtually impossible to unit test the calling code, unless you have another class that wraps this one, but then there is still not much advantage in having this static method. But maybe it's out of scope for this question. Sorry for the noise. :-)

Comment: @GolezTrol: I see where you are getting at, MVC/ MVMM is our bread and butter but the OP is not on that level yet :)

Comment: Moving "if Page= ... then ..." to Execute leads to "Instance member 'CharPageControl' inaccessible here" error. Previous code worked fine.

Comment: Yeah, it's sunday night, so i haven't even thought about solving it myself :) But what i still don't get is why i need a custom constructor now when it's nothing but inherited Create.

Comment: @AlexNiman: good point, I would probably do that in another place in code, now my answer is totally broken ;)

Comment: @AlexNiman, the point I wanted to make  is that you don't need the form reference. you pass data to the dialog which the user can alter and then the code can use that data after `ShowModal` has been called. One thing I would change is to use `ModalResult` to make sure the user actually clicked OK button or just closed the form...

Comment: @AlexNiman: I updated my answer to convey what I meant with my first comment, happy easter :=)

Comment: Yeah, i got it :) Thanks a lot!